# Wordpress - duplicate search results listed?

Tags: php, wordpress

The theme used is CookingPress v1.2. - http://bit.ly/zgCtE0

**Problem:**
If "test-blog-post" has 5 tags and is returned in search results, then it will be listed 5 times in the results list.

**Question:**
Is there something I can add to the code below to correct the search results from being duplicated? If not, is there any other code that might cause this?

Below is the code that renders the search results (from **loop-search.php**).

```
   <?php if (!have_posts()) : ?>
        // No Results
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        // Show Posts
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the complete code. You have cut out the important stuff after "//Show Posts". Please post that code and please post the code that queries the database. I ask because I don't think that it is a WordPress native query. That is, I don't think vanilla Wordpress searches for tags at all. That means that this is a custom query or the developer has hooked into the WordPress query and altered it. Your question is not very answerable without that information.